# The reference which mentioned that the rotational symmetry guarantees the off-diagonal term of the conductivity matrix is antisymmetric?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, crystals, quantum-hall-effect

The two-dimensional conductivity matrix can be written as $\sigma=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\sigma_{xx} & \sigma_{xy}\\\sigma_{yx} & \sigma_{yy}\end{array}\right]$ which represents the current response to the enternal elecric field $j_\alpha=\sigma_{\alpha\beta}E_\beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $x$ or $y$.

The anti-symmetry part of $\sigma$ matrix is non-zero when time-reversal symmetry is broken. If the system has rotation symmetry, at least 3-fold discrete rotational symmetry, the off-diagonal part can be proved to be pure antisymmetric $\sigma_{xy}=-\sigma_{yx}$ I proved it as follows:

The rotation operation matrix is $R=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{array}\right]$. When the system has 3-fold rotational symmetry $\theta=2\pi/3$, from $R\sigma R^{-1}=\sigma$, it can be proved that $\sigma_{xy}=-\sigma_{yx}$, as well as $\sigma_{xx}=\sigma_{yy}$.

Are there any references (papers or books) which mention this? I need some references to cite.

Comment: Why do you need a reference when you apparently have your own proof of what you want to show?

Comment: @ACuriousMind i want to cite the reference in my paper since the proof is too long.